# Can someone explain to me why my code isn't working? It's to do with the pillow module

Tags: python

I'm very new to Python and programming, so my understanding of lots of things is very lackluster, sorry if that means this is harder to read. I've been doing the CS50's Introduction to Programming with Python, and I'm currently File I/O and at the end we're creating a simple gif using the pillow module. It wouldn't properly work on codespaces so I opened up my VSCode and now although it does show the image, it's not acting as if a gif would and only shows the first image and not the second. Now if I'm honest I don't fully understand the code, but I'm TRYING! So was just wondering if it was something I've done wrong or basically what the issue is?

```
import sys

from PIL import Image

images = []

for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    image = Image.open(arg)
    images.append(image)

images[0].save(
    "giftest.gif", save_all=True, append_image=[images[1]], duration=200, loop=0
)
```

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72945610/669576), `append_image=[images[1]]` should be `append_images=image[1:]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I save an array of Pillow images as a GIF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72945567/how-do-i-save-an-array-of-pillow-images-as-a-gif)

Comment: When trying append_images=image[1:], I get back, TypeError: 'GifImageFile' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Forgot an `s` in my comment: `append_images=images[1:]`